# don't re-execute request while user is clicking repeatedly on fetch data button using rxbinding and rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android, reactivex, rx-binding

I have a RxView and I have set the click observer, I don't wanna always make new request per click.
The thing that I wanna is to ignore user clicks when the fetching data request is in progress only using Rxjava and Rxbinding.

```
button.clicks()
        .flatMapSingle {
            Completable.fromCallable {
                usersViewModel.users(emptyList())
            }
                .andThen(Request.users())
        }
        .doOnNext {
            Toast
                .makeText(this, R.string.users_updated, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
        .subscribe(usersViewModel::users) { Log.e(this::class.java.name, it.message, it) }
```

Is there any way except the ThrottleFirst?

Comment: Just disable button after one click. And if you want re-enable after your execution completes.

Comment: Thanks. its working solution, but is there any solution that uses **only** RxJava ?

Comment: I'm not familiar in Rx Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling and reenabling the button is much more straightforward, but you can use backpressure:

```java
button.clicks()
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP)
        .flatMapSingle ({
            Completable.fromCallable {
                usersViewModel.users(emptyList())
            }
            .andThen(Request.users())
        }, false, 1)
        .doOnNext {
            Toast
                .makeText(this, R.string.users_updated, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
        .subscribe(usersViewModel::users) { 
            Log.e(this::class.java.name, it.message, it) 
        }
```